# Make a Date/Time still counting even at runtime (Date/Time still counting even program run)

Tags: c#, winforms

How do i make Date/Time still counting? i already tried this below code:

```
dateTimeContainer.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
```

But, when i run the program, date/time is stopped while we run the program.

Question: How do i make that date/time still counting even after program runs?

Comment: So the time stops for you? Amazing.

Comment: Answer: count in other thread.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` only returns the current time at the moment it was called. If you want to keep up-to-date, you have to call it every time you need it.

Comment: You can use a timer which ticks every 1 second and update the text on label in every tick

Comment: i mean, the time in the program stops, not in the real time.

Answer (score 4):

An instance of [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime) represents a moment in time, once created it is immutable (any "modifying" methods—eg. [`DateTime.AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.addhours)— return a new `DateTime` instance rather than changing the subject of the call).

While this immutability might occasionally be something to work around more often than not it is more useful (eg. remembering when some event happened).

If you want to update just read from [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.now) (or [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.utcnow)) again.